# What is the correct URI to send a message with MSGraph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a webjob that has been successfully using MSGraph to interact with Office 365 to subscribe to WebHook notification of new messages, to read new messges, to query for and read unread messages, to set Read status, and to PUT messages into a mailbox.  I am now attempting to add the ability to send messages.  Unfortunately, I have come across numerous specifications for the "Send" URI, and all of them return an error code of 400, "Bad Request".

Here is a list of what I have found in various documents - none of which work.

```
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/messages/{id}/send where {id} is undocumented
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/messages/{id}/sendmail where {id} is undocumented
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/sendmail
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/send
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/microsoft.graph.sendmail
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{senderEmailAddress}/microsoft.graph.send
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{senderEmailAddress}/send
    POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{senderEmailAddress}/sendMail
```

Can someone tell me what the correct URI is?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), it will save you some time:

[image]